# How to dynamically create regular expressions based of a user input

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a program that gets an input from the user, then makes a regular expression using that input.

Here is some example code:

```
<input id="a" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Create" id="b" />
<script>
(function (z , code) {
    var input = document.getElementById("a"),
        b = document.getElementById("b");
    function primary(){
        var regEx = new RegExp("[A-Z]{3}[ ]\d{9}[ ]" + input.value.toUpperCase(), "g");
        alert(regEx);
    };
    b.addEventListener("click",function(){
        primary();
    }, false);
}(this, document));
</script>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Progo/ahy8p/)**

It works accept for this:

Say I use `FooBar` as my input. Instead of creating a regular expression that says, `/[A-Z]{3}[ ]\d{9}[ ]FOOBAR/g` I get a regular expression that says, `/[A-Z]{3}[ ]d{9}[ ]FOOBAR/g`. A `d` instead of `\d`.

Why is this not working properly? How can I correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you use the regex constructor you need to double escape special charaters, so `\\d`, etc.

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks! That sure fixed it! If you posted that as an answer I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MDN RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description),

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var re = /\w+/;
> var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
> ```

In your RegEx, `\d` is a special character

> \d     Matches a digit character in the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent
>   to [0-9].
>
> For example, /\d/ or /[0-9]/ matches '2' in "B2 is the suite number."

So, your RegEx, should have been like this

```
[A-Z]{3}[ ]\\d{9}[ ]   //\\d instead of \d
```